# How to allow plugins to have custom properties?

Tags: wpf

I have wpf app and I am allowing usercontrol plugins that implement
an interface.

i want to allow the plugins to have their own properties but I want to 
have these properties access from menu in the host.

How would this be architected best?

The properties could be string, double etc.

Malcolm

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I want to have these properties access from menu"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could pass in the menu to the plugin (when initialising it as part of the IPlugin interface) and it could populate the entries in the menu itself.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to use an Attribute on the custom properties and get them by reflection from the host.